# CalculateArea using poymorphism and virtual method - not getting proper result.

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have write a code to calculate the area of different shapes using polymorphism (Virtua & Override Method) but not getting correct result. :(

Below is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double side = 0;
        double length = 0;
        double width = 0;
        double height = 0;
        double baseoftriangle = 0;
        double radius = 0;

        UserChoice:
        Console.WriteLine("For what shape you want to calculate the Area:\n1. Sqaure\n2. Rectangle\n3. Triangle\n4. Circle");
        Console.Write("Please Select the number from above options: ");
        int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Write("Please enter the side of square: ");
                side = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.Write("Please enter the length of rectangle: ");
                length = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Please enter the width of rectangle: ");
                width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.Write("Please enter the height of triangle: ");
                height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Please enter the base of triangle: ");
                baseoftriangle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.Write("Please enter the radius of circle: ");
                radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Choice, please try again!");
                goto UserChoice;
        }

        CalculateArea Sqa = new Square();
        Sqa = new Rectangle();
        Sqa = new Triangle();
        Sqa = new Circle();
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            Sqa.Area(side);
            Sqa.ShowResult();
        }
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            Sqa.Area(length,width);
            Sqa.ShowResult();
        }
        else if(choice==3)
        {
            Sqa.Area(height, baseoftriangle);
            Sqa.ShowResult();
        }
        else
        {
            Sqa.Area(radius);
            Sqa.ShowResult();
        }


        ChoiceOfAnotherCalculation:
        Console.Write("\nDo you want to calculate area of any other shape? Give input in Yes or NO: ");
        string choice1 = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (choice1.ToUpper())
        {
            case "YES":
                goto UserChoice;
            case "NO":
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Choice, please try again!");
                goto ChoiceOfAnotherCalculation;
        }
    }
}
class CalculateArea
{
    public double result;
    public virtual void Area(double side)
    {
    }
    public virtual void Area(double length, double width)
    {
    }
    public void ShowResult()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Your Result is {result}");
    }
}
class Square: CalculateArea
{

    public override void Area(double side)
    {
        result = side * side;
    }

}
class Rectangle:CalculateArea
{
    public override void Area(double length, double width)
    {
        result = length * width;
    }
}
class Triangle:CalculateArea
{
    public override void Area(double height, double baseoftriangle)
    {
        result = (height * baseoftriangle)/2;
    }
}
class Circle:CalculateArea
{
    public override void Area(double radius)
    {
        result = 3.14159 * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

For Rectangle & Triangle, I am always getting 0 as a result and for square I am getting result from circle. I think this issue is causing because of the way I have created objects for class (May be because of lack of understanding in polymorphism).

Can someone please have a look and let me know what is the actual problem here.

Apart from this also I would appreciate your efforts if you can provide me the solution with get & set properties for each class. I have tried to write the code (Where I have tried to define the property in each derive class as well as in base class) but was getting various errors that's why I have jump on above solution.

I will also request please do not downvote the question as system won't allow me ask question for a long time. As this is the only platform where I can understood the things properly.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Move your `CalculateArea Sqa` declaration above your switch statement. In your switch statement assign Sqa to the appropriate shape. The `if` statement can then go away as you ask the shape `Sqa` to calculate its area. Polymorphism means you don't need switch statements (or an equivalent if..else if..else) when you ask a class to do something and it has different behavior depending on the concrete class. The base class should be called `Shape` not `CalculateArea` - use nouns for classes, verbs for methods in general. It should be abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `switch` statement, after case 1, your program will exit. This is because you have used `return;`, you might have intended to use `break;` instead. Break statement ensures that your switch wont fall through to the next statement, and a return statement would terminate the execution immediately.

Correct case statement should be like this

```
case 1:
    Console.Write("Please enter the side of square: ");
    side = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    break;
```

**EDIT**

Base class will only hold an abstract method to calculate area, which should be implemented by inheriting classes.

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    // must implement by inheriting classes
    public abstract double CalculateArea();
}
```

Each shape would calculate area using different parameters, therefore you should create properties that would be required by that specific shape.

```
public class Square : Shape
{
    // properties differ based on the shape.. 
    // eg: triangle needs height and base
    // edit CalculateArea method based on the shape
    public double Length { get; set; }

    public override double CalculateArea()
    {
        return Length * Length;
    }
}
```

Implement just like you did before, create an instance of the shape then pass the required parameters and invoke `CalculateArea()` method, that would return a `double` value:

```
double length;
Console.WriteLine("Enter length of one side: ");
if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length))
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, must be a number or decimal value.");

Square sq = new Square();
sq.Length = length;
Console.WriteLine(sq.CalculateArea().ToString("F"));
```

Comment: Many Thanks Abdul, I got confused between these return and break. Thanks for letting me know. Could you also please help me to solve this query where I need to use properties also to complete this code. Currently I have not added any properties in it.

Comment: @Shan Which properties? you have a `result` property right to store the value after calculating in `Square` class?

Comment: with reference to  properties I mean here get and set methods. Actually what I want is Polymorphism with encapsulation.

When I take any value from user so, then I will send these value to methods through properties where we can validate the result. 

Also my query is when we are using polymorphism, then can we use properties in derive class? If, yes then how can we transfer the value into these property through derive class object.

Comment: here's an example on how to use polymorphism with shapes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

Comment: Hi @abdul, Many Thanks for this. I still have a confusion to create the property in polymorphism where I need to take the value from users.

But I have tried to wrote the code for the same problem but without using properties, and still facing issues. I have updated the code & problem in main issue can you please suggest me what need to do here. I know these are silly questions but I think this is the platform where I will get the proper response and answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For polymorphism your classes should look like this:

```
abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract double Area {get;}
}

class Square: Shape
{
    public double Side {get;}
    public override double Area => Side * Side;
    public Square (double side)
    {
       this.Side = side;
    }
}

class Rectangle:Shape
{
    public double Width {get;}
    public double Length {get;}
    public override double Area => Width * Length;
    public Rectangle (double width, double length)
    {   
       this.Width = width;
       this.Length = length;
    }
}
```

etc.

With this in place, you can create the Shape once during the first case statement and can then use the `.Area` property on it in your output.

You should not have code to do output in your shape class, keep each class focused on one thing (SRP).

Your shapes should track their own properties because you may later want to add, say, a 'Description' property that uses those properties to describe the shape.